# Question about topology definition?

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem with this statement:

> Consider a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $\bar{S}=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $S^{c} \subseteq \partial S$.

The problem I have is with the $\subseteq$ part. We know by definition that $S\cup S^{c}=\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Why do we have the implication $\subseteq$ instead of $=$ or even $\supseteq $?

I hope my question makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the specific case in which $n=1$ and $S=\Bbb Q$: $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, its complement is the set of irrationals, and its boundary is $\Bbb R$ itself. This example already shows that $=$ and $\supseteq$ are both impossible.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott +1 Thank you! All I could think of were examples where $\partial S$ is a subset of  $S^{c}$.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $\partial S=\overline{S}-S^\circ$ (where $S^\circ$ is the interior of $S$). So if $\overline{S}=\mathbb{R}^n$, 
$$\partial S = \overline{S}-S^\circ = \mathbb{R}^n - S^\circ \supseteq \mathbb{R}^n-S=S^c.$$
The reason for the $\supseteq$ is that $S^\circ \subseteq S$, so $\mathbb{R}^n - S^\circ \supseteq \mathbb{R}^n-S$.

Edit: See Brian M. Scott's comment for a great example for why the other containment might not hold. I was trying to think of one myself!

Answer (score 1):

This relation says every point not in $S$ is a boundary point of $S$.  If it had said $\text{“}\supseteq\text{''}$, it would have said every boundary point of $S$ is not in $S$.  Consider the set $S$ of all rational points --- i.e. points all of whose coordinates are rational.  Every point in $\mathbb R^n$ is a boundary point of $S$.